# Hash routing at single page with changing content

Tags: javascript, html

I have two pages and I need to make one using html and javascript

F.E. First page is a form and second page is a table to work with. So, after user submit the form, page have to update without refreshing. Form have to disappear, and table have to appear instead of it. How can I do it without PHP or frameworks like AngularJS and with #blabla routing or something HTML and JS only?

Comment: An ajax request to load your html page (jquery make it easy. jQuery.ajax or jQuery.get) and history object to push your route https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API If you need croos-browser for history you can use this https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/

Comment: And what if I have to use pure HTML and JS without server-side? I have two pages and need to show both of them at one single page, and URL must be like **index.html** -> **index.html#game** and so on.